# UITextView subview UIImageView hiding entered text and scrolling with texts iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uitextview, subview

I have `UITextView` in my iPhone app. In the `UITextView i have added UIImageView as subview`. When the entered text reaches the `final height the texts are scrolling to top`. Instead the `UIImageView (with image) also scrolling top`. How can i handle to stop the image scroll and allow the text to scroll? Here is my code for your reference,

```
    messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 5, 210, 30)];
    messageTextView.delegate = self;
    messageTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    messageTextView.clipsToBounds = YES;  
    messageTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
    messageTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    textViewImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 210, 30)];
    textViewImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"textbg.png"];
    textViewImageView.contentMode    = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    textViewImageView.contentStretch = CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0);  
    [messageTextView addSubview: textViewImageView];

    [messageTextView sendSubviewToBack: textViewImageView];
    [messageTextView addSubview:textViewLabel];
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this? Thanks in advance. Looking forward your reply.

[image]

Comment: Why dont you set that image as the UITextField background?

Comment: You mean add UITextView as subview of UIImageView my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you considered to position the imageView behind the textView? Or is there any reason that forbids such a layout?

something like that:

```
UITextView *messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 5, 210, 30)];
// ...
messageTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:messageTextView];

UIImageView *textViewImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 5, 210, 30)];
// ...
textViewImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:textViewImageView];

[self.view sendSubviewToBack:textViewImageView];
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help.
Use the scrollview delegate to reposition your image when it reaches the bounds.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {

        CGRect imageFrame = textViewImageView.frame;
        imageFrame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y - (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height);
        textViewImageView.frame = imageFrame;

    }       
}
```

Comment: am not using UIScrollView. Any suggestion please?

Comment: UITextView inherits from UIScrollView so this should still work. As long you set the textview delegate. If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: This doesn't work.....at all. It's the correct concept, but changing the origin.y is not enough...it makes the view behave wildly ... (remember there are also other constraints shaping its appearance)

Comment: @Radu You're probably right. This used to work in the iOS 6 era. Might not be the best solution anymore. Maybe using normal constraints will fix this problem now?

Answer (score 0):

**This should work:**

```
[yourTxtView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your image.png"]]];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my image size is too shorter than uitextview width and hight. So when i add setBackgroundColor it showing multiple images. Could you please give some suggestion to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: I think that your UITextView should have some fixed size, the same size as your background image. If you post a screenshot it will be easier...

Comment: I have added a screen shot for your reference. Thank you.